# DataReader Object Reference not set error

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datareader

I have made an application that automatically mails some files.
The problem now is, that I have the emailaddresses in another database, (sdf-file).

I want to search for the value of "filenaam" which can be something like "q1869".
That variable has to be searched in the database (automail.sdf). And when ther is something with the "q1869" in it. Then get the value of that row, in the second field, which is in my case "email".

Now I tried a lot of things.
But I stumbled upon a problem right now.

When I run this code, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error at `string emailaddress = getemail.ExecuteScalar().ToString();`

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    //Automail mail = new Automail();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //timer aanmaken, interval instellen en aanzetten + gegevens in datatable laden
        mytimer.Tick +=mytimer_Tick;
        mytimer.Interval = 10000;
        Methods methods = new Methods();
        Populate();


    }



    public OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};uid=AYISHB;system=NLPROD;dbq=MMASHB MMASHB;dftpkglib=QGPL;languageid=ENU;pkg=QGPL/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512;qrystglmt=-1;signon=1;trace=2");
    public iDB2Connection conn = new iDB2Connection("DataSource=NLPROD;UserID=AYISHB;Password=AYI;DataCompression=True;Default Collection=mmashb;");
    public SqlCeConnection dbcon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=E:\Users\Ali\Documents\automail.sdf");
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.dsv.com"); // smtp client maken
    int aantalmails = 0;



    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    ///////////////////////////methodes//////////////////////////
    //Vul dataGridView1 methode

    public void Populate()
    {

        dt.Clear();

        OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM SELECTIE ORDER BY OMSCH",con); //querycommand om gegevens te openen

        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cm; // data adapter command aanmaken



        da.Fill(dt); // datatable vullen met de data





    }



   public void sendMail()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Populate();
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {

                for (int x = dt.Rows.Count - 1; x >= 0; --x)
                {


                    int i = x; //i is aantal rijen
                    int r = 1;
                    string query = dt.Rows[i][r].ToString();// zet de querynummer om in een string
                    string filenaam = query.Trim(); // haal de overtollige spaties uit de naam en filenaam is de querynmr


                    SqlCeCommand getemail = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT email" + " FROM Emails" + " WHERE (query LIKE @querynaam)" , dbcon);
                    getemail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@querynaam", filenaam);
                    string emailaddress = getemail.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


                    MessageBox.Show(emailaddress);


                        //try
                        //{


                        //}
                        //catch (Exception ex)
                        //{
                        //    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        //}







                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"M:\dtf\" + filenaam + ".dtf"); // start de dtf bestand met de zelfde querynaam op de M schijf


                    Thread.Sleep(15000); // wacht 15 seconden

                    try
                    {
                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();//


                        mail.From = new MailAddress("ali.yilmaz@nl.dsv.com");
                        mail.To.Add(emailaddress.ToString());
                        mail.Subject = "Report " + filenaam + " DSV REPORT";
                        mail.Body = "Dear Customer,\nthis message is an automated mail sent by an unattended server. \nThe attachment included in this mail is: " + filenaam + "\nPlease do not reply to this email \n \nThis mail has been sent on " + string.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss:tt yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now);

                        System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
                        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"M:/" + filenaam + ".xls");
                        mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

                        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ali.yilmaz@nl.dsv.com", "Uran1234");
                        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

                        mail.Dispose();



                        Thread.Sleep(10000);

                        string sourcefile = @"M:\" + filenaam + ".xls";
                        string destinationfile = @"M:\verzondenreports\" + filenaam + ".xls";


                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"M:\verzondenreports\" + filenaam + ".xls"))
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Delete(@"M:\verzondenreports\" + filenaam + ".xls");
                            System.IO.File.Move(sourcefile, destinationfile);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.IO.File.Move(sourcefile, destinationfile);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    try
                    {
                        iDB2DataAdapter data = new iDB2DataAdapter("SELECT FROM SELECTIE ORDER BY OMSCH", conn);

                        data.DeleteCommand = new iDB2Command("DELETE FROM SELECTIE WHERE" + filenaam, conn);
                        data.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                    filenaam = "";




                }
                dt.Clear();




            }
            else
            {
                dt.Clear();
                Populate();
            }
        }
    }
    ///////////////////////////methodes//////////////////////////

    //wanneer form word opgestart
    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //open connecties
            con.Open();
            conn.Open();
            dbcon.Open();
            //vul de tabel met de gegevens
            Populate();


        }
        catch(iDB2Exception ex)
        {
            // als connectie niet lukt weergeef foutmelding
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);


        }



    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Close();
        conn.Close();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = ("Running...");
        mytimer.Enabled = true;


        Thread t = GetT();
        t.Start();


        //Populate();

        //if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
        //{
        //    int count = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        //    for (int x = 0; x <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count; x++)
        //    {
        //        int i = 0;
        //        int r = 1;
        //        string number = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[r].Value.ToString();
        //        string filenaam = number.Trim();
        //        textBox1.Text = filenaam;

        //        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"M:\dtf\" + filenaam + ".dtf");
        //        i = i++;
        //        Thread.Sleep(100);
        //    }
        //    //OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("DELETE FROM SELECTIE WHERE *", con);
        //    //OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter();
        //    //da.DeleteCommand = cm;

        //    iDB2DataAdapter data = new iDB2DataAdapter("SELECT FROM SELECTIE ORDER BY OMSCH", conn);
        //    conn.Open();
        //    data.DeleteCommand = new iDB2Command("DELETE FROM SELECTIE", conn);
        //    data.DeleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    Populate();
        //}
        //conn.Close();
        //Populate();


    }

    private Thread GetT()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendMail));
        return t;
    }

    void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //sendMail();


    }

    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = GetT();
        t.Abort();
        label2.Text = ("Stopped...");
        mytimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getemail.ExecuteScalar()` will return null if there are no results, in which case `getemail.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` will throw a null reference exception.

You will need to check, something like this:

```
var result = getemail.ExecuteScalar();

if (result != null)
{
    string emailaddress = result.ToString();
    // Etc
```

Comment: I tried this, but I still get the same exact error. I am sure that the fields aren't empty. So is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Can you run this under the debugger and see exactly what type is being returned? And what happens when you try to inspect its value under the debugger? If what you say is true, it seems the exception must be happening inside the implementation of the type's `ToString()` method. But if it's just a `string` that's not possible...

Comment: It says that no type is being returned, so "null" is being returned. I don't know how I can get this to work, maybe if you could check my SQL-statement for errors?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't tell without a copy of the database... Can you try using something like Linqpad or Microsoft's Server Explorer or their SQL Server Management Studio to run the query?

Comment: I don't know if it's forbidden to post links, but this is my database:
http://www75.zippyshare.com/v/39403011/file.html

Comment: From looking at it, I can only suppose that `querynaam` isn't set to an appropriate value.

Comment: principalID, email, query and subject <-- these are my columns

Comment: @AliYilmaz Yes, but what is `querynaam` set to?

Comment: The filename that has to be exported by starting a *.dtf file. The file exports a *.xls file e.g "Q1896.xls". And it has to search the filename "Q1869" in the database, and send it to the email-addresses in the database which are in the record of Q1896.

Comment: Don't worry, the "filenaam" has a value in it, @querynaam is parameterd with "filenaam". So that part is correct, I assume

Comment: Can you figure out what the problem is, I tried almost everything, but nothing seems to work...

Comment: @AliYilmaz I'm afraid not - the only thing I could think of was that `filenaam` doesn't contain a value which is matching the email addresses in the `query` column.

Comment: The "filenaam" doesn't match any email (filenaam contains "Q1869"), but it has to match another column called "query". So that it can extract the second column of that row, which contains the email, so it has to search indirectly through the "query" number (Q1896).

Comment: @AliYilmaz Well I looked at your database and the `Query` column has values like `aliyi*****5@gmail.com` in it. (I changed part of the email address to ****** there in case the email address is sensitive) and your `Email` column has things like `Q1986` in it. Have you got the columns the wrong way around?

Comment: Okay, I corrected that part, but still. That didn't change the fact it doesnt work. Also when I run it with the query I get this error -`--------------------------

---------------------------
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 8,Token in error = FROM ]
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------`


With query `SqlCeCommand getemail = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT FROM Emails WHERE query = @querynaam", dbcon);`

Comment: I already solved it...    `SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
                        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Emails WHERE query = @querynumber", dbcon);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@querynumber", filenaam);

                        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
                            emailaddress = rdr["email"].ToString();
                            subject = rdr["subject"].ToString();
                            
                            
                        }`

Answer (score 0):

If you do `var result = getemail.ExecuteScalar();` you will see that `result` is `null`, hence you cannot call `ToString()` on it. You will have to check the return value to see if it is usable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is probably wrong and thus, the ExecuteScalar returns null. You cannot use ToString method on null. Verify that your query will return a result and I suggest you test your result from ExecuteScalar for null before applying ToString.

Comment: I am sure there is information in the fields, but my application doesn't seem to read it. Is there maybe something wrong with my SQL-statement ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
var emailaddress = getemail.ExecuteScalar();

if (emailaddress != null) {
    result = emailaddress.ToString();
}
```

`getemail.ExecuteScalar()` returns `null` when there are no records. hence, you need to check condition in if block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
emailaddress = Convert.ToString(getemail.ExecuteScalar());
```

you can proceed with

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailaddress))
{
  // do something with email

}
```

And Change below lines

```
SqlCeCommand getemail = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT email FROM Emails  WHERE query LIKE @querynaam" , dbcon);
getemail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@querynaam","%" + filenaam + "%");
```

Comment: I tried this also, but it keeps giving me the "Object reference not set" error. I think it may be something with my sql statement, but I am not sure. What I am 100% sure of though, is that the database contains 3 records.

Comment: what are the column names of Emails table?

Comment: principalID, email, query and subject

Comment: @AliYilmaz check my updated answer, you need to add `%` when you add `LIKE` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line of code instead of getemail.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

```
Convert.ToString(getemail.ExecuteScalar())
```

The Convert.ToString() method will handle null for you, if the value is a non-null value it will return the string and of it returns null it will simple return an empty string.

Thanks